# Suspend Service Bus sending message when debugging Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

When I am debugging Service Bus trigger Azure Function, the breakpoint will be hit again for the multiple time with same Service Bus message.

This occurs if I stepping through the code for too long time. It seems Service Bus will send the message again after some minutes and thereby the Function App will execute again.

Any idea how to handle this so that we can work efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus has a message-locking mechanism. Think of it as a lease time within wich a message has to be either completed or returned. If none of that happens, the lease expires, and another competing consumer can receive the message. This is what's happening in the code that's being debugged longer than the lock duration time. The lock duration time is set on the queue, or subscription messages are retrieved. The lock duration can be set up-to 5 minutes. You can verify and set the `MaxLockDuration` on the entity to the max (5 minutes) or shorten your debugging session.